# How to get Yammer Note's versions information

Tags: yammer

I used yammer rest api “https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/notes/[:id].json" to get the note details, but I found that the response doesn't contains the note's version information, only has the latest_version 
"latest_version": {
    "id": "id",
    "title": "title",
    "created_at": "create time",
     ...
}

So, I want to konw that is there any way to get note's version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Yammer Note versions by adding `include_versions=true` to your querystring. For example:

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/notes/[id].json?include_versions=true

The JSON response will include "versions" which is an array of hashtables including the id of each revision. The way Yammer saves Notes is each original note is saved by an id and that id is used to access the latest version of that note every time. As notes are saved again, they are saved with a new id and associated with the original note. So you will have to programmatically access the list of version numbers in the hashtables and then use the same URL you normally do to retrieve that revision.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works for me. And I want to know something more, I used 
"https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/notes.json?included_versions=true"
 to get a list of notes, I want each note including versions, but it did't have. So how to do?

Comment: The versions array will contain a hashtable for each version. Each version will include a download_url that you can use to access the content of the note. There doesn't seem to be any other way to programmatically access the other revisions that I can see.

Comment: To elaborate, you will get a URL like this from download_url: https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/notes/[original_id]/versions/[revision_id]/download

Comment: It seems that if I want to access a note's all versions, I need request "yammer.com/api/v1/notes.json" to get the note's id and then request "yammer.com/api/v1/notes/[id].json?include_versions=true" to get all versions, right?

Comment: Correct, you will need to programmatically access the list of notes, then programmatically access the versions of each note.